# Only displaying pre-installed applications on android device

Tags: android

So I am using the Home sample to build an application that creates a second home screen for the user. The idea is to be able to have only one user account yet restrict certain access to chosen applications. I have managed to ensure that all of the applications are invisible in the XML yet I am struggling with how to change this to make certain apps visible.

Is it possible to write a whitelist of accepted apps for instance the preinstalled apps or child friendly apps for children who game using the android device and then put in a Java method to access this white list? This is the only way I can think to make it work.

If anyone knows the correct way can you please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your app can restrict access to other apps. Since it runs under Android with the same level of privileges as any other app and thus can be killed, switched, paused, etc. by the user. You would have to mod the OS itself.

Comment: I hadn't thought about restricting access, the plan was that all other apps are still available if the user exits my app then the other apps can be used, just through my UI view certain apps would be invisible. I can make them all invisible this way but I'm unsure how to cherry pick apps for the visibility treatment.

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is part of the newly released Android 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I discovered how to do this.

In the home sample they provide a for loop in the Home.java file that covers all apps and displays them. It take a simple if statement to restrict the apps that can be viewed -

`// for loop is here`

```
if (info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName.contains("com.android"))
```

`//then the rest of the home sample is here.`

Still very basic but provides me with a good enough UI so that kids cannot see apps I don't want them to.

Comment: You can also check for `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM` to allow access to those system apps that may not be from Google, like the default camera app(may be from Samsung, HTC, etc).

Comment: Thanks Geobits I will have a look.